# Qt - opening url's

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with opening url using Qt.

I have a Dialog with a PushButton on it and the clicked() slot:

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"));
}
```

But when I click it I get an error:

```
ShellExecute 'http://www.google.com' failed (error 31)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows? Maybe check what the error code means in general, and see if it makes sense in your situation.

Comment: ShellExecute suggests you're on Windows. Which Qt version is that?

Comment: Try calling `ShellExecute()` directly and see if you get the same error code.  If so, it could be that your machine is configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ShellExcecute Error 31 means `SE_ERR_NOASSOC` - there is no application associated with the given file name extension. Are you sure that your system configuration is correct? Did you try to use `openUrl` with other type of files (for example some local files)?